# What can be the reason when a neural network fail to map a relationship between data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, data-science

I have a regression problem where I should predict the bearing(azimuth) and distance from other features that I have in my dataset ( features example are Acceleration, speed, longitude, latitude etc..).

This should be actually an easy task for a neural network to do but my neural network model can't fit the data. It started with a big loss value and then it decrease slowly until it reach 6000 which is an unacceptable loss value and it stays there like it is stuck there or something. First I thought maybe this is happening because I'm predicting two outputs instead of only one so I tried to split the task by creating two separate neural networks, one is responsible for predicting the distance and the other for predicting the bearing but that also didn't help and I noticed the networks are stuck at high loss value somehow.

I mean they start to learn and already did a good job for the first 5 or 10 epochs but then they stuck there and stop improving. Now I'm not a beginner in the field, I tried changing optimizers, complexity of the network by adding layers, neurons etc.., normalizing or standardizing the inputs but none of that helped. I started to think maybe there is something wrong with the data, after all it is a regression problem and not a classification problem which I think that it can be badly affected by outliers in my data or something like this.

Unfortunately I don't have a good knowledge in data science or how to process the data. I read about log transformations and something like that but I didn't get it correctly. So my question is can this be a reason why my Neural network is failing to learn? I'm seeking advice how should or can I preprocess my data and how can I be sure whether it is a data problem?

My data are a CSV file that I load it with pandas, after feature selection I had only 6 features and 1 output so my inputs shape is (40000, 6) and output is (40000, 1). I also use this function to normalize my inputs (as you can see I'm trying both z_score and minmax normalization but that didn't help):

```
def normalize_inputs(dataset, method='z_score'):
    
    df = dataset.copy()
    
    if method == 'z_score':

        for feature in df.columns:
            df[feature] = (df[feature] - df[feature].mean()) / df[feature].std()

        return df
    
    elif method == 'min_max':
        for feature in df.columns:
            
            max_value = df[feature].max()
            min_value = df[feature].min()
            df[feature] = (df[feature] - min_value) / (max_value - min_value)
        return df
    
    else:
        raise Exception('the normalization Methods can be z_score or min_max!!')


# normalize outputs:
def normalize_output(target, method='z_score'):
    y = target.copy()
    
    if method.lower() == 'z_score':
        norm_params = {
                        'bearing': {'mean': None, 'std': None}, 
                        'distance': {'mean': None, 'std': None}
                      }
            
        for col in y.columns:
            # store the mean and std values for later 
            norm_params[col]['mean'] = y[col].mean()
            norm_params[col]['std'] = y[col].std()
            y[col] = (y[col] - y[col].mean()) / y[col].std()
    
    elif method.lower() == 'min_max':
        norm_params = {
            'bearing': {'min': None, 'max': None}, 
            'distance': {'min': None, 'max': None}
          }
        for col in y.columns:
            # store the mean and std values for later 
            norm_params[col]['min'] = y[col].min()
            norm_params[col]['max'] = y[col].max()
            y[col] = (y[col] - y[col].min()) / (y[col].max() - y[col].min())
        
    return y, norm_params



X_norm = normalize_inputs(X, method='z_score')
#y_norm, norm_params = normalize_output(y, method='z_score')


# check the values after normalization
X_norm.describe()
```

This is my Neural network model declaration with pytorch:

```
class BearingNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_features=X.shape[1], n_out=1):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            
            nn.Linear(n_features, 140), 
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(140, 64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(64, n_out),
        )
        
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.model(x)
        return out
```

then I'm using the skorch API because it implements automatically cross validation from a pytorch model (skorch is just a scikit learn wrapper for pytorch, but I also used pytorch and get the same results):

```
bearing_nn = NeuralNetRegressor(
    
    BearingNetwork,
    criterion=nn.MSELoss,
    optimizer=optim.Adam,  # I also tried other optimizers
    max_epochs=100,
    batch_size=128,
    lr=5e-2,  # also tried many other learning rates
    iterator_train__shuffle=True,
    iterator_train__num_workers=4,
    iterator_train_pin_memory=True,
    callbacks=[R2, rmse, Checkpoint(), EarlyStopping(patience=100)],
    device=device
    
)
```

I read a lot of blogs to how to preprocess data but it is somehow hard to grasp. for example I tried to plot a pairplot using seaborn and here is the result:

[image]

How can I interpret this data? Does this plot somehow shows that my data are bad? Most of the tutorials that I found, shows simple datasets that have linear relationships and positive or negative correlations but in my case there is no linear relationships as I can see from the graphs.

I am hoping to find some transformation for my dataset so that the network can better learn the data because I'm sure that there is nothing wrong with my model implementation since I used pytorch, skorch and keras and I got the same results always.

Comment: What is the shape of your network ?  
If you want to detect if your network is at fault or if the problem is not solvable with your data, you can try other machine learning algorithms, e.g. gradient boosting, and then check the loss to see if it learns successfully.

Comment: @Osbark Inputs have a shape of (40000, 7), output (40000, 1)

Comment: How many layers does it have, and what are their dimensions ?

Comment: @Osbark I already explained that I tried many architectures. I tried from 1 to 10 layers and from 3 to 10000 neurons. the Error have nothing to do with my neural network architecture that's why I'm posting this question. I think something is wrong with the data or maybe the data need a transformation

Comment: Have you tried a different machine learning algorithm, like gradient boosting ? If it is unable to learn, this will most likely mean that there is not enough information in the data.

Comment: What was your loss function and did you use like a sigmoid or tanh function on your last/output layer? This looks like a regression task.

Comment: @KlausJude No of course I didnt. I know it is a regression task. like I said I used many combinations from sigmoids to tanh to relus, I tried all things like I explained but nothing worked. loss functions that I tried are MSE and RMSE but like I said the loss value is always high. I mean the model learn for the first 10 epochs but then it stuck there

Comment: @Osbark I tried to use Random Forest and Gradient Boosting as you suggested, apparently they are fitting the data better than the neural network. here are the stats: (Random Forest stats => train score = 0.9410229856895217 | validation score = 0.581838525737892) and (Gradient Boosting stats => train score = 0.7325884483976517 | validation score = 0.40200558267445713). why is that do you have any explanation? I thought neural network can fit any non linear function even only with one hidden layer

Comment: @basilisk Theoretically yes, however there are pitfalls in practive. Can you post the code of one of the architectures you tried ? Without the details it is hard to guess where something went wrong

Comment: @Osbark Ok I added both my pytorch and skorch model declaration. the other code will not be helpful since it is only calling data and normalizing it and then take a look at the results after training